# Trying to re-create HMAC using SHA1 in PHP

Tags: php, ssl, aes, tls1.2, hmac

I have the following decrypted message, which has previously been encrypted using AES-256-CBC

```
240dcbefc0f82fadc00ef8494488aaa81400000c2def01e79fec6c4d9a822358dd8a910cac606e8afcb607793cb442093a56b7b40b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b
```

I derive the following 20 BYTE HMAC from this message:

```
dd8a910cac606e8afcb607793cb442093a56b7b4
```

My goal is to re-create this HMAC using PHP, I attempt with the following code:

```
$iv = hex2bin('240dcbefc0f82fadc00ef8494488aaa8'); // random iv - first 16 bytes of the message
$message = hex2bin('1400000c2def01e79fec6c4d9a822358'); // the actual message being decrypted - next 16 bytes
$key = hex2bin('b109124b62e2c8b8248e9865990325fddcc61143'); // encryption key

$hmac = hash_hmac('sha1', $iv.$message, $key);
print($hmac); // 03634ba3f4a0c854a0b791d27f331ecdfad1e87e

$attempt2 = hash('sha256', $iv.$message, true);
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha1', $attempt2, $key);
print($hmac); // 39ad1fb94ab251cdaf3f21cf8673e070733f4e16
```

I know I'm missing something but I'm struggling to understand the HMAC process as it's very confusing to me.  Any help or advise is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why are you using SHA-256 before the HMAC call? Why not directly use `$iv.$message`? Besides that, I'm pretty sure TLS uses MAC-then-encrypt - it's one of the reasons why there aren't any CBC ciphers in TLS 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on a random blog post online :D

here is what worked for me:

```
function check_mac($seq, $type, $msg, $key) {
    $SequenceNumber = pack("NN", 0, $seq);
    $Type = pack("Cnn", $type, 0x0303, strlen($msg));
    $data = $SequenceNumber . $Type . $msg;
    $calculated_mac = hash_hmac("sha1", $data, $key, true);
    print(bin2hex($calculated_mac) . "\n");
}
```

Also, the IV does not need to be included, just the message by itself as the $msg variable

Blog Post:
https://adayinthelifeof.nl/2013/12/30/decoding-tls-with-php/